# Visual Studio 2008 error

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I am trying to run a C# project on my VS 2008 the following message appears:

"Project "defining" could not be opened because Microsoft Visual C# 2008 compiler could not be created.Query Service for {        } failed."

I have uninstalled and installed VS 2008 twice. Also installed a patch for it. But the error persists. I am able to run Visual Basic projects.

Any of you have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769071/microsoft-visual-c-2008-compiler-could-not-be-created-please-re-install-visual)

Comment: hi could you tell me what exactly to do? coz I'm not really sure how to implement what has been given in the solutions present in the link. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with VS 2010. I tried opening VS with both the /ResetSkipPkgs and  /ResetSettings switches, which didn't work. I finally fixed it by deleting the following registry key.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Visual studio will lose all user preferences the next time you start it.