# Project <Name> could not be opened because the Microsoft Visual C# 2010 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After installing [Debugger Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh227299) and restarting Visual Studio, I get this error for each project when opening a solution:

> Project <Name> could not be opened because the Microsoft Visual C#
>   2010 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.

I tried all of the answers from this question with no luck: [Microsoft visual C# 2008 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769071/microsoft-visual-c-2008-compiler-could-not-be-created-please-re-install-visual)

So far I have:

- Tried the /resetsettings argument
- Tried the /ResetSkipPkgs argument
- Tried removing the whole key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

Any other ideas other than reinstalling VS and/or SP1?

VS Version: 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Thanks!

Comment: [Application Can't Load. Visual C# 2015 RC Compiler Could Not Be Created](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36800682) may help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After trying everything, I fixed this by reapplying the SP1, without needing to reinstall the whole VS. Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: How do you reapply it?

Comment: @JoePhilllips just run the SP1 installer again

Comment: @alf Thanks. I had a similar problem and nothing would work. Had to completely reinstall new version of VS

Answer (score 25):

1. Open VS command prompt
2. Run the following command

   `devenv /resetsettings`
3. Open your Project

Comment: I got "Project 'X' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created" in Visual Studio 2015. devenv /resetsettings fixed that issue for VS 2015 too.

Comment: @Sergey it didn't solve mine, I am still getting "Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created" while creating a new project.

Note: I tried all the mentioned answers!!!

Comment: @Sergey I am facing the same problem with same VS 2015. But it message me to reinstall VS. While I have run to repair it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the error message also included "Query Service for { } failed." I tried opening VS with both the /ResetSkipPkgs and  /ResetSettings switches, which didn't work. I finally fixed it by deleting the following registry key.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Visual studio will lose all user preferences the next time you start it.

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 - My issue was in the sln file. Reverting to previous revision resolved the issue.