# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 repair error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I'm attempting to repair VS2015 with Update 1 installation due to the following error when loading projects:

- Project 'projectName' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.
- .cs files are loaded as white plain text
- "An error occurred loading this property page" error occurs when opening some of the C# Text Editor options.

However the repair fails with the following error:

> [15D4:410C][2015-12-07T11:08:31]i301: Applying execute package: vs_minshellres, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{7FF53256-7BAF-3EFA-91B4-DB65F37EB5E9}v14.0.23107\packages\vs_minshellres\vs_minshellres.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1"'
>   [43D0:2388][2015-12-07T11:08:40]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package **(vs_minshellres) failed: Error Message Id: 1316 ErrorMessage: The specified account already exists.**
>
> [15D4:410C][2015-12-07T11:08:41]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.
>   [15D4:410C][2015-12-07T11:08:41]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [43D0:2388][2015-12-07T11:08:41]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

Comment: You might have to bite the bullet and just reinstall vs. I know it sucks, it takes all day to install.

Comment: Just did a quick google actually and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493302/application-cant-load-visual-c-sharp-2015-rc-compiler-could-not-be-created

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried the solution however the result from the command was: No assemblies found matching: Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.Interop

Comment: Ok, I'm attempting to uninstall then reinstall it now

Comment: I have encountered problems with my antivirus application active during installation. You might wanna disable it.

Comment: Thanks, It worked after reinstalling it. The question remains why it didn't work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daniel Hakimi and @scofield_foxriver for your input.

After uninstalling VS2015 Enterprise and its related components, restarting and Re-installing it's working now.

Comment: MS needs to get their crap together

Comment: I have uninstalled/reinstalled 5 times now, manually editing all registry and removing all the bits from around the filesystem with no luck. My only option is to now reinstall Windows ... why it stopped working i have no idea, so much for deadlines!