# visual studio 2015 new project issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 new project problem, whenever i try to open new project this dilog box shows i try all project web etc same probelm occure,  I have tried repairing, uninstalling and installing nothing seems to fix my issue.

I get errors  when I try to create a new project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall Visual studio.
- Restart pc.
- Install it again .

[Answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493302/application-cant-load-visual-c-sharp-2015-rc-compiler-could-not-be-created)