# Failed to Locate Azure SDK v2.8 on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I joined a team using Visual 2015 + Azure + Node  + React to develop a product. 
When I installed azure sdk v2.8 for visual studio 2015, the azure project dont compile. Installation was proper and no install errors existed.

So SDK was downloaded from this site and followed installation instructions at the site

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041

*Azure SDK 2.8 was not available on Web Platform Installer
I am using a Windows 7 Professional Environment on 64 bit Core i5 (3rd gen) platform

I get below error in the Azure project.

Error       WAT080 : Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK. Please make sure the Microsoft Azure SDK v2.8 is installed.  <>.Azure   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  1089

Is there any idea ?

Comment: SDKs are available in this URL https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ , click "Visual Studio 2015"

Answer (score 1):

I researched for awhile and looked at other stack overflow posts from older situations and it was such a pain for someone to just give a clear explanation instead of pointing me to the same download sdk website. Took me awhile to figure this out correctly, but this is what I found.

I tried installing through Platform Installer and it looks like they removed 2.8 from the installer so that is not the option anymore. So you have to manually install the 2.8 sdk from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041 . When you download the files, you do need to follow the install instructions and run each installer manually (If you have newer versions, it will warn you saying it cannot run that installer and you have to go into control panel to delete the newer versions if any). I noticed after running the MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi that the v2.8 folder did appear in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\ . I still had issues and added it to my PATH just incase. Im not sure if it helps or not. But I did read from another post to delete the cache files for vs2015. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38092339/4705236 . Also make sure to Restart Visual Studio 2015 after your done with changes and want to test to see if its installed correctly.