# Project could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows 10 PC on which I have installed VS 2012, VS 2015, and VS 2017.

The solution was created for 2015 platform toolset. When I open the solution in VS 2017, and try to build it, it works fine.

If I open it in VS 2015, and build it, that also works.

But when I try to build it using:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" [link to .sln file] /Build "Release|Win32" /Out "build.log"

I get the error message:

Project 'URCSLogger' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.

I tried everything [in this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493302/application-cant-load-visual-c-sharp-2015-rc-compiler-could-not-be-created#) but nothing worked. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `MsBuild.exe [Path to your solution(*.sln)] /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86` ?

See MSDN documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Please ensure you have `Release | x86` configuration settings in your solution. See [How do I specify the platform for MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155492/how-do-i-specify-the-platform-for-msbuild)

Hope this helps.