# issue with Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, telerik, iis-7.5

When I run my website, I get the following error message

**Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd'**

Here are the contents of web.config...

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

If I comment out the handlers entry.. I get the following error message...

**'~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager**

I am total at loss on how to fix this. I do not know how to use Smart Tag. I have googled, looked into SO, looked into Telerik site and can not find solution any where. I do not know if the problem is in my web.config, Virtual directory or where??? My colleagues have the same code base and web.config and it works for them.

**EDIT**
Here is my development machine setup...

Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1 64 bit OS

Visual Studio 2010 Enterprise Service pack 1 IIS version 7.5

Please help.

Comment: What web server ? IIS 7 or IIS 6, or maybe VS.NET development server

Comment: just answered your question in EDIT

Comment: look in system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config is there something in system.webServer handlers section related to Telerik

Comment: both files do not have any mention of Telerik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem *wont* be in the IIS config; as the error message specifically refers to a Web.config file, so that's going to be in .Net

What happens if you comment out the httpHandlers entry rather then handlers ?

Edit: After looking at your web.config file, the only thing I can suggest is changing the format of the system.webServer.handlers.add part from

```
<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
```

to:

```
<add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"  path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
```

And that's because that's what Telerik suggest to be the best practice; If that doesn't work then I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas tonight, but please leave the question open, perhaps someone with a better idea will see it in the morning.

Comment: Just occured to me, make sure the web.config file you're looking at isn't the only one in the solution; .Net lets you have multiple config files at different directory levels.

Comment: when I comment out httpHandlers entry.. I get the error : Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd'

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have multiple config files ?

Comment: I have web.config, web.debug.config, and web.release.config

Comment: If your web.config doesn't have anything confidential in it like a password or anything, you might consider posting it here:  http://shorttext.com/ and using the private option; then you can put the link into a comment here and I can have a look for you ?

Comment: Most likely this is a IIS 7 and it ignores httpHandlers settings, handlers on IIS 7 are set in system.webServer

Comment: It's iis7.5 so that could be the issue, if he comments out the first one, it says he needs the section, if he comments the other one, it says he's  got a duplicate. It's a bit odd for sure! Happy for you to step in with your own answer...

Comment: He said "comment out the handlers entry" so that can mean anything :) And I presume that he is commenting handlers section under system.webServer, btw. don't have my own answer just commenting, to me all looks ok

Comment: @AntonioBakula yes he did, but I assumed he meant handler as one of the config options is handler, and one is httpHandler.

Comment: key is nlhibj. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Sorry, it says that's invalid :<

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12133/discussion-between-dotnet-practitioner-and-russ-c)

Comment: Sorry, I can't do chat at the moment - it's 2am in the morning here, I will amend my answer.