# Error: The Web Server 'http://dnndev/Website/DesktopModules/DNNSample/' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke-5

i followed the video tutorial there at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKW97CqVb1Y.

but when i create the project am getting an error

**"The Web application project DNNSample is configured to IIS.The Web Server  "http//dnndev/Website/DesktopModules/DNNSample/" could not be found."**

i have tried restart IIS etc by googling. but none helped.([Satck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889421/the-web-application-project-is-configured-to-use-iis-the-web-server))

Am using VS10. IIS is 7.5. C# template i have downloaded.

Any help.. am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have same problem, i solved that At the host name “dnndev” to the bindings of IIS 7.5. you can Open Internet Information Services (IIS) manager and right click on your website and then click to Edit Bindings... then you add to new binding which has name is "dnndev".