# How do I get to IIS Manager?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7.5, iis-express, controlpanel

In trying to reconnect and reconfigure an existing project on a new machine, I find here ([The Web Application Project [...] is configured to use IIS. The Web server [...] could not be found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889421/the-web-application-project-is-configured-to-use-iis-the-web-server) ), based on the err msg I got on opening the project, that I need to go to IIS Manager (I performed the tasks prior to that in Russ C's answer, installing IIS 7.5 Express and rebooting). However, Russ goes on to write, "*Next, go to your IIS Manager...*" and that I haven't been able to do/find.

So I found this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472(v=WS.10).aspx, where these instructions are given:

*To open IIS Manager from the Start menu
Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
Do one of the following:
If you are using Windows Vista® or Windows Server® 2008, click System and Maintenance, and then click Administrative Tools.
If you are using Windows® 7 or Windows Server® 2008 R2, click System and Security, and then click Administrative Tools.
In the Administrative Tools window, double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
To open IIS Manager from the Search box
Click Start.
In the Start Search box, type inetmgr and press ENTER.*

As this is Windows 7, I tried  System and Security | Administrative Tools, but there is no IIS Manager in the list. So I then tried the "inetmgr" route and that, too, failed (it opens a "Search Results" dialog with "No results matched you search" or similar wording).

So how can I locate the IIS Manager so that I can create anew or reattach the configurations the asp.net is failing to find?

### UPDATE

I had to manually add support for asp.net 4 in IIS Manager for my project to quit whining. Why wouldn't this automatically be configured when installing asp.net 4?!? Anywho, for the benefit of future onreaders, here is what I had to add in its full color glory:

[image]

So here's how it looks at the end:

[image]

I don't know why v2 is needed and, if it is, why version 3 is not, but the important thing (for me, now) is having v4 support.

### UPDATE 2

Right-click solution, there is a "Use IIS Express..." menu item. If you select that, you see:

[image]

...so maybe all that lying on my back, getting oil in my hair was unnecessary - just select this and all that behind-the-scenes stuff would have been taken care of automagically?

Comment: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv - "This folder is empty" Maybe I installed the wrong thing? In installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

Comment: Mine had it installed, but typing iis or the likes into start search returned nothing found. inetmgr from run got it opened. I pinned it to the start menu!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

First of all, you need to check that the IIS is installed in your machine, for that you can go to:

Control Panel --> Add or Remove Programs --> Windows Features --> And Check if Internet Information Services is installed with  at least the 'Web Administration Tools' Enabled and The 'World Wide Web Service'

If not, check it, and Press Accept to install it.

Once that is done, you need to go to Administrative Tools in Control Panel and the IIS Will be there. Or simply run inetmgr (after Win+R).

Edit:
You should have something like this: 
[image]

Comment: It's now allowing me to check those things; clicking them toggles them from filled-blue to empty (white/blanco). All of the suboptions refer to IIS6. Aren't there newer versions available?

Comment: That installed it, but now I get, "asp.net 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server. You need to manually configure your Web server for asp.net 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly.", and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836228/asp-net-4-0-has-not-been-registered (1st comment) that is not unusual.

Comment: Well, you have a few things to check: 1. Verify you have installed the ASP.NET 4.0 2. in the IIS, verify that in the 'ISAPI Restrictions' the ASP .NET 4.0 is Allowed. 3. Check you have in the App Pool of your site the ASP.NET 4.0 Selected

Comment: OK, running inetmgr now, I do see a slew of icons, but to take first things first, how do I determine ASP.NET 4.0.2 has been installed? My "ASP.NET" section there has ".NET Authorization, " .NET Compilation," etc. but I don't see how to tell which version of ASP.NET is there...

Comment: In Control Panel, I can see a whole bunch of ASP.NET stuff, such as:
Microsoft ASP.NET MVC2, -MVC3, - Web Pages, - Visual Studio 2010 Tools, etc. Also, I have "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile", "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended" etc.

Comment: In inetmgr | Application Pools | Basic Settings, I see: "ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated, .NET Framework version: v4.0.30319.

Comment: Okay, so I found I've got asp.net 4 installed; now where do I find the "ISAPI Restrictions" setting? Oh, I see - I had to go back to the top of the tree to see that.

Comment: What "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" shows as being allowed is:

ASP.NET v2.0.50727

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

(and Framework64, too...and Active Server Pages).

So do I need to add an entry for v4.0.30319?

Comment: I did that (for both "Framework" and "Framework64"); the project no longer complains about asp.net missing, so I guess that did the trick. "What a tangled web we weave!" as some wise guy (spider?) once opined.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the IIS Management Console is installed.

Answer (score 3):

On a Windows Server 2016 I opened `Server Manager` from the start menu search. Then clicked `Tools` on the top right. Then found `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`

Or click `win + r` then type `inetmgr` then hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

To open IIS Manager, click Start, type inetmgr in the Search Programs and Files box, and then press ENTER.

if the IIS Manager doesn't open that means you need to install it.

So, Follow the instruction at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7