# Web Server Could not be found

Tags: asp.net, iis, localserver

I Use Win 10 and VS 2015. I'm  trying to open project but. it doesnt loaded this message appear :

the web application is configured to use iis the web server could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to look at, these are:

1. Is IIS installed on your machine, press the Start key and type Programs and Features, select Add or Remove Windows Features and check the IIS has been installed
2. When opening up Visual Studio (if you are running a project that uses IIS) you need to right click the Visual Studio shortcut and select Run as Administrator

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Open the csproj file (with notepad if necessary) and change this setting:

```
<WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
</WebProjectProperties>
```

To :

```
<WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
</WebProjectProperties>
```

Then reload the project (right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click reload).

Also see the answer by Doug S for more information and useful comments: [The Web Application Project [...] is configured to use IIS. The Web server [...] could not be found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889421/the-web-application-project-is-configured-to-use-iis-the-web-server)