# The Application is configured to use IIS (Visual Studio 2017/2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

**Hi Guys I just Cloned my project from a repository.
I am getting this Similar error 
The Web Application Project […] is configured to use IIS. The Web server […] could not be found.

I do have IIS  Manager on my pc. one of the solution is to set  True on my cs.proj file but when i do it auto imports  a port number. when i try to run the application with that port number the application hangs(load forever). 
What are possible ways to solve this error ?**

Comment: Try this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/12930137/8207463

Comment: @BerBar I used <UseIIS>False</UseIIS> solution. the problem is that the project gets loaded but when i try to run it it keeps hanging on http://localhost:64126/ and there is no output . Meaning the server is not responding

Comment: have you try open the project folder and delete {Project}.csproj.user and reload it ?

Comment: Yes the localhost keeps on loading and no output is received

Comment: What is the version of your .NET and IIS ?

Comment: For IIS -10.0.16299.15 .NET -4.5

Comment: I am using IIS that came with windows 10

Comment: VS as administrator ?

Comment: Try to reset the IIS also: iisreset: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-web-server-is-not-configured-correctly?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks i managed to solve the solution.

Comment: > Reseted IIS Server
> Published the project
> Added Project to IIS server(Windows)
> On Visual Studio Choose to run project Local IIS Server instead Of IIS Express Server.

Comment: Kgetini Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Just to register an answer for all getting into the same problem under the same scenario, as we discuss and resolve it from the question's comments:

Ps: as i said this solution works for this particular scenario, maybe anyone else has to apply a different approach!
In this case, try to follow the below link for other solutions!

[The Web Application Project [...] is configured to use IIS. The Web server [...] could not be found.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10889421/8207463)

1. Reset the IIS; (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-web-server-is-not-configured-correctly?view=vs-2019)
2. Publish the project;
3. Add it to IIS Server;
4. Run it using IIS Local (not the IIS Express)